# Extract first and last name from email address

Tags: regex, google-sheets, re2

I've seen a variety of this everywhere but nowhere that answers my questions specifically. I need to extract a first name and last name from an email address but also need to make the case proper with capital letters for first and last name.

I've tried to use: `=ArrayFormula(PROPER(REGEXREPLACE($E3:$E,"@(.*)","")))` but yes, this extracts it and makes it proper case but leaves the '.' in the middle of the first and last name. I'd love to get eyes and help on this please as I'm a beginner learning more and more about Google Sheets.

[image: See my example here]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=ArrayFormula(PROPER(substitute(regexextract($E3:$E,"(.*)@"), ".", char(10))))
```

or,

```
=ArrayFormula(PROPER(substitute(regexextract($E3:$E,"(.*)@"), ".", " ")))
```